# How to disable a class member function for certain template types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, enable-if

It seems to be simple, but I have some difficulties with the syntax of `std::enable_if`

The situation is actually quite simple.

a template class with template parameter `T`

2 functions which shall not be implemented for one specific type of `T`.

Both functions have no parameters or return values of `T`

One function accepts an `int` and the other function returns an `int`.

Any simple example ?

Or is there another option (C++11) which does not use `std::enable_if` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's really simple. Just remember to use another template parameter that is defaulted to the class/struct template parameter.

Suppose you want a class `foo<T>` with two members, `void foo<T>::bar1 (int)` and `int foo<T>::bar2 ()` and suppose that you want that `bar1()` and `bar2()` are implemented only if `T` is different from `long`.

You can do as follows

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct foo
 {
   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<U, long>::value>::type
      bar1 (int)
       { }

   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<U, long>::value, int>::type
      bar2 ()
       { return 0; }
 };

int main()
 {
   foo<int>  fi;
   foo<long> fl;

   fi.bar1(0); // compile
   fi.bar2();  // compile

   // fl.bar1(0); // compilation error
   // fl.bar2();  // compilation error
 }
```

There is a danger: someone can bypass your control and explicit the `U` type as follows

```
foo<long> fl;

fl.bar1<long long>(0);
```

To avoid this problem, you can improve your `std::enable_if` test as follows

```
   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if
         <sizeof(U) && (false == std::is_same<T, long>::value)>::type
      bar1 (int)
       { }

   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if
         <sizeof(U) && (false == std::is_same<T, long>::value), int>::type
      bar2 ()
       { return 0; }
```

If you can use a C++14 compiler, using `std::enable_if_t` you can avoid a couple of `typename` and a couple if `::type` and semplify the code as follows

```
   template <typename U = T>
   std::enable_if_t<sizeof(U) && (false == std::is_same<T, long>::value)>
      bar1 (int)
       { }

   template <typename U = T>
   std::enable_if_t<sizeof(U) && (false == std::is_same<T, long>::value), int>
      bar2 ()
       { return 0; }
```

As of C++20, the `requires` keyword makes things much simpler:

```
   void bar1 (int) requires (!std::is_same_v<T, long>)
       { }

   int bar2 () requires (!std::is_same_v<T, long>)
       { return 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks it perfectly did whant I wanted. But I still lack some understanding. Why it is not possible to use directly 'T' instead of 'U' ;  <typename U = T>  ?  Also the 2nd example sizeof(U) how can this result in 0 ?

Comment: Didn't quite understand how including sizeof(U) helps

Comment: sample code on ideone, if anyone wants to try.
1. without sizeof(U) check - https://ideone.com/k9cvnC
2. with sizeof(U) check - https://ideone.com/EoORcv

Comment: @SahilSingh - helps because transform the `std::enalble_if` test in a test dependent from `U` and `T` and not only from `T`. If the test depends only from `T` (that is the template parameter of the class, not of the method) SFINAE doesn't works.